# xcode 5.1 cause performance bug

Tags: xcode, opengl-es

I've been developing an OpenGL ES game on Xcode 4.2 (llvm 3.0) and I just switched to XCode 5.1 (llvm 5.1), now I see a massive drop in performance. When compiled on XCode 4.2 I get fixed frame time of 33.3ms (because it uses vsync). When compiled with 5.1 the frame time is 42ms. All code and project settings are exactly the same (except for compiler version, obviously).
Has anyone seen a similiar problem to this?

Comment: Unlikely to be your problems, but just in case: I noticed that Xcode 5 uses debug builds by default. Not sure if that was already the case for Xcode 4? The only time it does a release build is if you specifically build for deployment. You can set it to use release builds in settings for the scheme.

Comment: No, I build release versions always

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I had left some vertex attributes enabled which weren't being used. This causes the opengl driver to use slow software copy of vertex data, but for some bizzare reason the bug never manifest itself when using the older version of xcode.

Comment: Glad you found it! That is weird! Would you mind mentioning which attributes? I'd like to avoid the same problem in my code.

Comment: If you have any attribute enabled with glEnableVertexAttribArray and for any reason, it's missing the corrosponding glVertexAttribPointer then the driver can't transfer the data via DMA. That's the bug that I had in my code